# ¿Cómo contar cuantos registros están relacionados con otros registros de otra tabla?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo básicamente estas 3 tablas:

Tabla 1: especialidades:

- codigo_especialidad (PK)
- especialidad_nombre
- especialidad_estado

Tabla 2: especialidades_subespecialidades:

- codigo_especialidad_subespecialidad (PK)
- codigo_subespecialidad (FK)
- codigo_especialidad (FK)
- especialidad_subespecialidad_estado

Tabla 3: subespecialidades:

- codigo_subespecialidad (PK)
- subespecialidad_nombre
- subespecialidad_estado

En la tabla 1 y 3 hay una relacion de muchos a muchos, así q la tabla 2 es la que rompe esa relacion.
Lo que trato de hacer es obtener todos los atributos de la tabla 1(especialidades) adicionando una columna al resultado indicando cuantas subespecialidades tiene cada especialidad. Para ello hice la siguiente consulta pero no me muestra cuantas subespecialidades tiene cada especialidad, me muestra un numero fijo en todos los resultado:

```
SELECT codigo_especialidad , especialidad_nombre, especialidad_estado, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM especialidades INNER JOIN especialidades_subespecialidades ON especialidades.codigo_especialidad = especialidades_subespecialidades.codigo_especialidad WHERE especialidades.codigo_especialidad = especialidades_subespecialidades.codigo_especialidad ) AS "total especialidades" FROM especialidades WHERE especialidad_estado = 1 GROUP BY codigo_especialidad
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes resolver mediante una consulta enlazada por las llaves primarias y foráneas que vinculan a todas las tablas con la ayuda de `INNER JOIN`.

- Primero obtienes el nombre de la especialidad
- Posterior haces un conteo de las veces que aparece el id de la subespecialidad pero en la tabla pivote
- Haces un primer `INNER JOIN` uniendo a las tablas pivote y a la tabla especialidades
- Haces un segundo `INNER JOIN` uniendo a las tablas pivote con la tabla subespecialidades
- Finalmente agrupas por la columna que no esta calculada que sería: `especialidades.especialidad_nombre`

CONSULTA:

```
SELECT especialidades.especialidad_nombre, 
       COUNT(especialidades_subespecialidades.codigo_subespecialidad) as Total
FROM especialidades
INNER JOIN especialidades_subespecialidades 
    ON especialidades.codigo_especialidad  = especialidades_subespecialidades.codigo_especialidad
INNER JOIN subespecialidades 
    ON subespecialidades.codigo_subespecialidad = especialidades_subespecialidades.codigo_subespecialidad
GROUP BY especialidades.especialidad_nombre;
```

Nota.

Si deseas también obtener a las especialidades que no tienen alguna subespecialidad asignada entonces usa `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Hola, encontré una pequeña falla en tu consulta, resulta que solo esta realizando la suma d todos aquellos que tienen asignado al menos 1 subespecialidad a la especialidad, pero no muestra los demás registros de especialidades que no tienen asignado ninguna subespecialidad. No me había dado cuenta de eso porque en ese momento cuando probé la consulta ya tenia todas las especialidades con al menos una subespecialidad. Te agradecería si lo corregís por favor. Gracias

Comment: No es un error como tal @Leonidas pero si necesitas las especialidades que no tienen ninguna subespecialidad entonces deberás pasar de `INNER JOIN` a `LEFT JOIN` y listo

Comment: Pues esa es la intención de un INNER JOIN solo incluir registros que tengan al menos una relación, caso contrario aplica lo que te digo

Comment: Solo pasar de `INNER JOIN` a `LEFT JOIN`? Nada mas? Porque acabo de hacerlo y me sigue mostrando el mismo resultado.

Comment: Debes pasar ambos inner join a left join, lo acabo de probar y funciona

Comment: Si tienes razón, funciona, el problema era esta condición que le puse a la consulta: `WHERE especialidades.especialidad_estado = 1 AND especialidades_subespecialidades.especialidad_subespecialidad_estado = 1`, trato de obtener los registros que estén activos y que no tengan el estado en 0 porque eso representa que el registro se elimino lógicamente y no debe mostrarse ni contabilizarse en los resultados, pero en este caso si lo esta contando, la condición WHERE era para eso, para evitar que cuente los registros en estado 0. Pero cuando pongo la condición sale el mismo resultado que el anterior